# Use environment variables in docker

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, parameter-passing, dockerfile

I have implemented docker project for automated setup. I use docker 1.9 on Ubuntu Server and utilize feature `build-arg`. I using it for set dynamic subdomain in apache virtual hosts file.

```
 docker build --no-cache --build-arg domain=demo1.myapp.com -t imagename .
 docker run -d -p 8080:80 imagename
```

I use domain and replace it in virtual hosts file using sed command in my script file

```
sed -i -e "s/defaulthost.com/$domain/g" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myApp.conf
```

My Dockerfile had code

```
ARG domain 
RUN /bin/sh /script.sh $domain
```

Now I need to migrate application on AWS where I get Amazon Linux AMI. But here I get supported docker version 1.7, which do not support `build-arg`. I tried to upgrade but lot of dependencies block me.

Now I decide to use ENV environment variables like below.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 -e domain=demo1.myapp.com
```

I also changed Docker file like

My Dockerfile had code

```
RUN /bin/sh /script.sh
```

But It look like they not working in my scenario as at build time sed script replace empty value in apache file and build process failed.

If it is not possible without build arg or I am doing wrong way of set/use ENV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, AWS can support docker 1.9.
See for instance "[Getting overlay networking to work in AWS with Docker 1.9](http://sirile.github.io/2015/11/25/getting-overlay-networking-to-work-in-aws-with-docker-19.html)"

- use a Docker Machine version 0.5.2-dev, as [explained here](https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)
- use the [right AMI (Amazon Machine Image) Ubuntu 15.10](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/15.10/release/)
- Set up the [AWS environment variables](http://sirile.github.io/2015/08/05/part-2-scaling-in-amazon-aws-vpc-with-docker-docker-machine-consul-registrator-haproxy-elk-and-prometheus.html)

---

If you chose to remain with an old AMI and its docker 1.7, then [`-e` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) are for runtime only (creating/running containers), not build time (image).

That means if your `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` was: `/script.sh`, using *inside* the script `$domain` (and then launching your main process), that would work.

Comment: Yes luckily I myself found environment issue yesterday. As little experience in Docker, I do not have idea if script must be run with CMD not with RUN to utilize environment variables. So after running script in CMD, now environment variable seems to work.

Comment: For first one, Yes I know I can replace Ubuntu with Amazon EMI, But that would be the last solution if no alternative exists.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj I agree: I just wanted to cover all angles by mentioning the AMI part.